# How to - regression of a noisy titration curve?

Tags: regression, correlation, sampling, modeling, chemometrics

I'd appreciate advice on the correct statistical method to analyse a dataset -

Dataset is basically a titration curve consisting of [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] pg of starting material and 8 replicates in each 'pg bin'.  In 'stage 1' of the process each bin is labeled separately, in 'stage 2' all bins are pooled into one tube and amplified together and in 'stage 3' this is thrown into a DNA sequencer and bins are separated based on the labels.
So: the original input is a defined quantity of material and the final output is a number and what I would like to know is how accurately the output reflects the input.  This feels like some kind of regression but I'm not sure what to use.  The mean of 8 replicates?  Their median?  Something to do with the variability between them?  Something based on a binomial sampling (with different bins having a different expected value?)?

Below is an example dataset - the x axis is the titration curve bins ('0 pg' is background process noise), the y axis is the 'output number' and the barplots are over the 8 replicates.  There are 2 batches which are basically a repetition of the same experiment.

Thanks (and apologies if this has been asked before)!

[image: Sample dataset]

Comment: Do you expect a linear relationship between your dependent and independent variables, the amount of beginning material *x* and sequenced DNA *y*? (to use simple linear regression and correlation coefficient)

Comment: Ideally, yes.
But I also expect noise when you get too close to 0 and I expect differences between batches.

If I do regular linear regression can I then solve a 'reverse problem'?  E.g given a datapoint assign its most likely bin and give a confidence interval for that assignment?

Comment: What is the reason for expected difference between batch 1 and batch 2, other than random error? Is the random error at x=0 (noise) a constant, independent of *x* (linearity, homoscedasticity assumption)?

Comment: The mechanism for the expected difference is unknown and hidden (strange things happen in biology labs...).  The two batches (and another I didn't show) will hopefully give me a measure of the size of the error.

Error at 0 is likewise a type of 'batch effect' which I don't know how to model (I just use it to set a 'noise threshold' - the data you're seeing is after filtering so remaining x=0 values are those that escaped the noise filter).

Comment: I cannot make sense of the barplots because they are inconsistent with the claim that each represents eight replicates. The leftmost one in Batch 2, for instance, explicitly exhibits three outliers (shown with plus symbols) and a stem (indicating at least one more high but outlying value), all of which are strictly higher than the upper limit of the box (which itself should be above at least three-quarters of all the data). Therefore this boxplot must represent around 16 or more replicates, not eight!  What's going on here?

Comment: For a beginning, please use a metric x-axis instead of bins/factor: the true concentration/amount is meaningful. And with 8 data points per concentration step and the scatter indicated by the boxplots, all points could be plotted.

Comment: BTW: what you show are not titration curves but a calibration (derived from the analysed titration curves).

Comment: With a noise level on Batch 2, I'd probably throw the whole batch away.

Comment: I'll try and post scatter plots later today...

Comment: @cbeleites The results are not binned in analysis but represent the actual amount used - each replicate is a certain amount of volume drawn from a sample of a specific concentration.  This is as close as I can get to 'true replicates' and introduces a sampling bias which should be purely stochastic.  So, using a metric x-axis would have all the dots in each bin exactly one above the other with some horizontal standard deviation due to sampling.

Comment: @whuber the leftmost noise bin does indeed have 16 points, good catch (the rest have 8).  It's a combination of 2 identical 8-point bins and because I only use it to assess background noise I didn't make this clear.  Sorry

Comment: @queryous: I'm aware that unless you have a reference measurement of true concentration/amount you'll have points at the same x-axis location. In any case, your x-axis is metric, not a factor: it doesn't matter that multiple points happen to have the same x location. But it does matter that 1 is twice as much as 0.5. You'll not be able to do a meaningful analysis ignoring this. I just used "bins" together with factor as you did so in your question.

Comment: BTW, your sampling error is hopefully random, not systematic (= bias): you should check your pipetting technique for bias / (re)calibrate your pipettes before starting important experiments ;-)

Comment: @cbeleites
well pipetting was with a robot so I don't expect too terrible of a sampling error :)

is your metric axis complaint semantic e.g. I should stop calling it 'bins' and just say these are the original values or do you want to actually change something in the graph?

words are a nuisance sometimes lol

Comment: It is about the fact that 1 is as far left of 0.5 as 2 is of 1: the x axis does not have a metric scaling. This would mess up any kind of linearity that you hope to see... pipetting robot: good. (I'm curious what the pipetting robot's error actually is, though) For human (in particular: student) prepared solutions I usually assume that instrument error on the signal << concentration error. (A judgment that enters the decision for classical/inverse least squares)...

Answer (score 3):

I did not yet understand what the task at hand is. But I'll try to start towards an answer.

> the original input is a defined quantity of material and the final output is a number and what I would like to know is how accurately the output reflects the input.

This is part of the *validation* of the analytical method.

> This feels like some kind of regression

This is one step before: you're talking about the modeling here. 
Yes: as the dependent variate is metric, this is a regression

> but I'm not sure what to use.

Without further information (such as I expect it to be linear from theory - see comments) we won't be able to answer this: the type of regression will usually be concluded from the expert knowledge about application, measurements and the actual data (including theory).

> The mean of 8 replicates? Their median? Something to do with the variability between them? Something based on a binomial sampling (with different bins having a different expected value?)?

You need to do exactly the same that the method asks you to do for real analyses. So if you want to use the mean of the replicates here, also analyses are required to do 8 replicates and then take the mean. This is rather unusual: one typically goes for the individual measuements, and I'd recommend to go through the whole data analysis (including validation) process for that easiest setup before thinking about more complicated protocols.

---

Sidenote: typically the calibration solutions are prepared from one stock solution or one stock solution for each of the replicates. Strictly speaking this has the consequence that the data points are not truly independent. While a mixed model would be a better description of the situation, my guess is that in the end you may be better off sticking to a least squares model unless you have specific questions that are only answered by the mixed model (e.g. variance between stock solutions).
IMHO you can do this if you validate with properly independent validation samples, i.e.

- validation samples prepared from unknown stock solution (replicate stock solution)
- randomize the order of measurements at least for the valdation samples

IMHO it is even acceptable if your judgment of the whole analytical method concludes that the likely sources of error are *not* this dependence of the samples. But you should report this.

---

Many chemical-analytical methods follow a sigmoid shape, even if they are expected to be "linear": at very low concentrations you may get a flat signal, e.g. due to cross sensitivities. At very high concentrations your detection saturates, thus the signal levels off. One part of method development is to find out the concentration range where linearity can be assumed.

Is that your task at hand?

---

> If I do regular linear regression can I then solve a 'reverse problem'? E.g given a datapoint assign its most likely bin and give a confidence interval for that assignment?

Most probably, you don't want to assign a most likely bin but instead want to predict a metric concentration. You can set up the regression model either as signal = f (concentration) or as concentration = f (signal). These ways are called  classical (aka ordinary) least squares regression and inverse regression, and they have different properties and assumptions.
Confidence and also prediction intervals can be calculated for both classical and inverse models.

---

Suggested reading: Here are some technical terms which I think may be of interest:

- limit of detection/quantitation (LOD/LOQ) is used to characterize the low end of possible concentrations for qualitative/quantitative analysis.
  There are norms how to measure these.
- classical (aka ordinary) regression vs. inverse regression. In particular, they differ in their assumption of error: classical least squares assumes instrument noise on signal >> concentration error in calibration samples; inverse least squares assumen concentration error >> noise on signal
- confidence and prediction intervals

---

Some rules (of thumb):

- One way of calculating the LOD is to use the concentration/amount corresponding to the mean + 3 standard deviations of the blank signal (attention: works only if the blanks are independent, measured properly, and cover all non-analyte influences that occur in the real samples). A quick and dirty guess from your plots puts this somewhere between 2 and 3 pg.
  A rule of thumb for LOD and LOQ is that the LOQ is typically ca. 3 LOD, which would put it somewhere around 5 - 10 pg, and thus basically outside the concentration/amount range your experiment covers. With the variance you show, you probably need to add measurements at higher concentrations/amounts.
- Concentration series for proving linearity should at least contain 10 equally spaced concentration steps (thus covering one order of magnitude).

Comment: Thanks! (Can't upvote due to <15 rep,sry)

I've been asking around campus for help as well and I suppose the best answer I have right now to 'what is the task at hand' is something like 'to quantify the variability in the real value given an observed value'.  This would more or less answer all my questions (and might be different for different observed values).  We've started looking at variance vs. mean plots and playing around with generative simulations, I'll see how it goes...  
I might do another experiment for more power, besides 10 equally spaced concentrations what would you recommend?

Comment: I think useful recommendations would require digging into your actual task/application, and you may not want to reveal details here. See if you can find someone on your campus (ask for analytical chemist/chemometrician or a statistician familiar with chemical analyses e.g. in the clinical lab). If you cannot find help, you can contact me directly - leave a comment here and I'll give you my email.